# Visual Studio 2013 introduces bug when you rename any variable

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, scope, refactoring, rename

Suppose I have a business class as under (Targeting framework .NET 2.0):

```
Public Class SomeBusinessClass

    Public Property _ReportName As String

    Public Sub New (reportName As String)
        _ReportName = reportName
    End Sub

    '//... Some other stuff...
End Class
```

Now, while refactoring, I realize that "`_ReportName`" does not look good. I rename this to "`ReportName`". This does not provide me any warning/message. It renames variable successfully.

Though in constructor, "`_ReportName`" has been changed to "`ReportName`" and it looks different, but since VB is case insensitive, it actually assigns "`reportName`" to itself **and introduces a *logical bug***.

Do we have any setting in VS 2013/2010 that warn me when I am trying to do such mess? Or do we have any tool that helps in achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler checks for local variable before class scope inside a method - so if they are spelled the same it wants to use the parameter. You can tell it to set the property like thus:

```
Public Class SomeBusinessClass

  Public Property ReportName As String

  Public Sub New (reportName As String)
    Me.ReportName = reportName
  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: He/She/You/They could also use `_ReportName = reportName` to use the free. secret backing fileld

Comment: @Plutonix, sure could =), I was addressing the naming convention vs parameter and showing how it could work with the same spelling.

Comment: @Plutonix, secret backing field can be used only if setter of property hasn't some other code

Comment: @OneFineDay:
Thanks for your suggestions. Plutonix/Fabio, backing fields are new learning for me.

But, is there anything that "prevent" me doing such things? Is there any settings that helps? Any tools?